# How do I make row separator/bottom-border that isn't 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I've got a set of tabular data that I'm presenting in a standard HTML table tag. The design calls for a one pixel separating line between each row as well as having all cells in a given row be vertically centered against each other. The various rows and cells can have an arbitrary height and need to grow based on the content inside of them.

The tricky piece here comes from the fact that the one pixel separating line is supposed to stop 15px from either side of the edge of the table. My initial inclination to solve this is to merely add a `border-bottom` to either my `<tr>` or `<td>` tags, however, I couldn't for the life of me figure out any sort of way to not get the line to go all the way across. If I put `<div>` tags inside of the `<td>` tags, I can then apply the border to there, but then my border bottom is right up against the bottom of the content rather than at the bottom of the row.

The only thing I've been able to make work feels really "dirty" to me.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">My table data</td>
    .... more cells here as needed
    <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works because I add those two spacer cells on either end of the row. I've even gone pretty far down some non-table solutions, but I always run into issues trying to get the content to grow correctly (i.e. no absolute positioning in the various rows) and/or getting things to vertically center and wrap like they are supposed to.

Anybody have any better ideas? If it helps, I'm only supporting "newer" browsers, e.g. IE9+/etc, including mobile.

Comment: Can you provide a visual depiction of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Borders are always going to fill 100% of the width of the element. You could try using a pseudo element like :before to create a physical line.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/YKp35/) close to what you need? I am not posting this as a solution. I am trying to just get a visual idea.

Comment: Instead of 15 px, have you tried using percentage like 85%, so if your width is always 15% from the border no matter how wide it is. And since the same style is being applied multiple times try using a class so you only need to change something once. For the 1 px spacing try padding or margin. You and use align center to center your div inside each cell

Comment: Yes @Harry, that's basically it. But with a variable number of columns that aren't fixed width.

Comment: @JackThor - The design pretty specifically calls for pixels. I try not to argue with the designers more than I have to ;-) Also, I'm using classes in the final design, what I posted above was just for simplicity of asking the question.

Comment: @Morinar: Is adding a dummy `tr` like that acceptable? Or do you need it without any change to the markup?

Comment: @Harry - I'm writing this from scratch. I can make the markup look like anything I want. I can even dump tables entirely if they will achievement what I want more easily.

Comment: @Morinar: In that case, how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/YKp35/1/)? (Note: The padding on each side is 15% of 200px so it comes to 30px, but we can work that out)

Comment: Somebody posted a solution and then deleted it that was pretty much exactly what I needed involving large side borders. I don't actually need the content of the table rows to go all the way to the edges, which I forgot to mention, and probably why the answer was deleted. For example, this is basically exactly what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/YKp35/2/ Whoever posted that should feel free to repost and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Morinar: That is strange, but did you manage to get hold of that code before it was deleted?

Comment: @Harry - Yes. That's where my fiddle came from.

Comment: @Morinar: Good, so case closed then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a new row between each pair or rows with colspan="n" where n is the total number of collumns, and inside that new row you put a div with the desired specs (I would say 1px height, for instance).

HTML, add this between your rows:

```
<tr class="test_tr" >
    <td colspan="3"><div class="test_div"></div></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.test_tr
{
    height: 1px;
}

.test_div {
    height: 1px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8eWR/

Comment: Yeah, that seems workable. I'm not sure it's any less dirty than adding extra `<td>` tags through. Perhaps I'll just have to make something dirty and move on with my life.